# Can we retrieve the applications currently running in iPhone and iPad

Tags: iphone, ios4

Can we retrieve the applications currently  running  in iPhone and iPad?

**UPDATE**

Can we do it in jail broken phones? Can we do it for an app for CYDIA Store?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

You can get a list of running processes and from process ids may be you can figure out which ones are system processes and which one are 3rd party apps, but anyway I don't believe you can use it in application for appstore. (code taken from [here](http://forrst.com/posts/UIDevice_Category_For_Processes-h1H))

```
- (NSArray *)runningProcesses {

    int mib[4] = {CTL_KERN, KERN_PROC, KERN_PROC_ALL, 0};
    size_t miblen = 4;

    size_t size;
    int st = sysctl(mib, miblen, NULL, &size, NULL, 0);

    struct kinfo_proc * process = NULL;
    struct kinfo_proc * newprocess = NULL;

    do {

        size += size / 10;
        newprocess = realloc(process, size);

        if (!newprocess){

            if (process){
                free(process);
            }

            return nil;
        }

        process = newprocess;
        st = sysctl(mib, miblen, process, &size, NULL, 0);

    } while (st == -1 && errno == ENOMEM);

    if (st == 0){

        if (size % sizeof(struct kinfo_proc) == 0){
            int nprocess = size / sizeof(struct kinfo_proc);

            if (nprocess){

                NSMutableArray * array = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

                for (int i = nprocess - 1; i >= 0; i--){

                    NSString * processID = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%d", process[i].kp_proc.p_pid];
                    NSString * processName = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%s", process[i].kp_proc.p_comm];

                    NSDictionary * dict = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithObjects:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:processID, processName, nil] 
                                                                        forKeys:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"ProcessID", @"ProcessName", nil]];
                    [processID release];
                    [processName release];
                    [array addObject:dict];
                    [dict release];
                }

                free(process);
                return [array autorelease];
            }
        }
    }

    return nil;
}:
```

Comment: @Krishnan, this code works on non-jailbroken device, but Apple may forbid using this feature in application. If you target Cydia store you can do that ( I think (but not 100% sure) I've seen an application that works like a task manager - displaying all running application and allowing to terminate them)

Comment: Thanks for that. If you get to know any other info regarding this, please share it.

Comment: You can definitely do something like this on the App Store. Here's the evidence: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8275578/how-to-get-information-about-free-memory-and-running-processes

Comment: @DmitryIsakov have you found a way around this for iOS9+ ?

Comment: @ValerioSantinelli: This method works *if you are outside of the sandbox*. If you want the list, create an unsandboxed helper and then use IPC to fetch it from that helper.

Answer (score 2):

Why would you loop until you run put of memory? I think this is a lot simpler ;)

```
size_t size;
struct kinfo_proc *procs = NULL;
int status;

int mib[4] = { CTL_KERN, KERN_PROC, KERN_PROC_ALL, 0 };

status  = sysctl(mib, 4, NULL, &size, NULL, 0);
procs   = malloc(size);
status  = sysctl(mib, 4, procs, &size, NULL, 0);
```