# What "kernel level C function" does Frenzapp use to detect running iOS processes?

Tags: iphone, ios

According to [this iphonedevsdk.com forum post](http://www.iphonedevsdk.com/forum/iphone-sdk-development/64426-detecting-installed-apps-frenzapp-does.html), Frenzapp uses two methods to detect other apps installed on an iOS device:

1. UIApplication canOpenUrl: to check
   if known custom URL schemas can be
   opened
2. A "kernel level C function",
   that is "authorized by apple".

What "kernel level C function" are they using?  Where is it documented?

Comment: Check my answer to similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4312613/can-we-retrieve-the-applications-currently-running-in-iphone-and-ipad/4312705#4312705 . I'm not sure if that's the approved method, but at least it gives you a list of processes)

Comment: good question, saw that app and was wondering myself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks to Vladamir and Stephen Darlington for commenting and pointing us at what is most likely the answer:

- The kernel C function is sysctl()
- It's documented [on Apple's iOS Developer site](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/System/Conceptual/ManPages_iPhoneOS/man3/sysctl.3.html)
- You need to call it with a certain set of arguments to get the list of running processes (ids and strings)

  - See [Vladimir's previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4312613/can-we-retrieve-the-applications-currently-running-in-iphone-and-ipad/4312705#4312705) or [This post](http://forrst.com/posts/UIDevice_Category_For_Processes-h1H) for example code

Comment: Actually, `sysctl` is documented (http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/System/Conceptual/ManPages_iPhoneOS/man3/sysctl.3.html) and is, therefore, "blessed" by Apple. The absence of documentation _does_ mean it's forbidden.

Answer (score 0):

Right, though the process list is both very limited and presupposes that the process is indeed "running" in the background.

The key for discovery is having a large enough inventory of both process names (but the background tasking can only go so far...) and URLhandlers. And only a few companies in the World (if that many) outside of Apple can actually do this well.

And of course, the Springboard has an open-socket protocol that lets the App Store app (and potentially other apps) query whether an app is installed or not... but that's actually a much tougher one to crack.