# how to get background process status(running/suspend) without jailbreak in ios

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ios4, ios5

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can we retrieve the applications currently running in iPhone and iPad](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4312613/can-we-retrieve-the-applications-currently-running-in-iphone-and-ipad)

What I want to know is if there is a way to get the current background processes status(running/suspend) without jailbreak in ios

Comment: Apps on non-jailbroken phones aren't supposed to have any way to know what's going on outside of their sandboxes, so no, I doubt there is any way (via the SDK apis) to get a list of other processes running on the phone or their current status.

Answer (score 1):

There are apps in AppStore doing exactly that(SYS-Activity Monitor for example). and they likely use method from [Can we retrieve the applications currently running in iPhone and iPad](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4312613/can-we-retrieve-the-applications-currently-running-in-iphone-and-ipad)
This method doesn't allow you to determine suspended apps.
It also doesn't allow you to determine which app is background(if you are background too - you can be confused)
also, applications are named as 'Mail','Phone',etc(not by package ids like com.apple.MobileMail). There are ways around this but they are require private APIs