# Can you find individual app usage duration using SpringBoard services framework or other private framework?

Tags: ios5, iphone-privateapi, springboard

I have a background service running on iOS5. I am trying to find the duration for which each foreground application runs. I came across this great post by Vikarti Anatra. 
[how to determine which apps are background and which app is foreground on iOS by application id](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8252396/how-to-determine-which-apps-are-background-and-which-app-is-foreground-on-ios-by)

This shows how to get the current foreground process. However, what I would like to know is if there is a method which will give me the start time of various processes launched by Springboard so I can compute the duration.

I am trying to create a log of apps launched by my users. This is not meant for app store certification and meant to be an internal organization tool.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Have you had a look at [SBApplication](https://github.com/thomasfinch/iOS-7-SpringBoard-Headers/blob/master/SBApplication.h)? Perhaps you could swizzle `-[SBApplication activate]` and `-[SBApplication deactivate]` inside SpringBoard.app and calculate the time between them?