# How to use Springboard framework in xcode 4.3.1

Tags: iphone

I want to use "springboard" framework , I have added that framework by drag and drop in xcode downloading from github.com , but when I want to run it I got some error :

> Undefined symbols for architecture i386:
> "_SBSCopyLocalizedApplicationNameForDisplayIdentifier", referenced
> from:
>
> -[ViewController getActiveApps] in ViewController.old: symbol(s) not found for architecture i386 clang: error: linker command
>
> failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

why this error any one have any idea. I think have some issue in "headersearch path" setting any one kindly say how to set this .
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Having the headers is not enough, you have to link to the springboard binary as well.

However, I'm pretty sure the springboard is not available inside an application, so even if you get it to link, I'm pretty sure calling any springboard method will fail.

What you need to do to use springboard's methods is to make a mobile substrate extension.

Comment: where I got this springboard binary have you any link , secondly I want to use this code in my project,   from this link

Comment: The springboard binary is inside the iPhone, you need a jailbroken iPhone to get to it. And I understand you want to use that code in your project, but it won't work in a sandboxed app because the springboard is not a framework and it's not available to call from inside an app.

Comment: I want to use this ans code  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8252396/how-to-determine-which-apps-are-background-and-which-app-is-foreground-on-ios-by