# Is there a private API to be able to detect what is current foreground app on iOS?

Tags: ios, iphone-privateapi

I am not planning to send this app to AppStore. It's just an experimental app. So, I am not worried about AppStore approval/rejection.

I am looking for a way, how I can determine

a) What is the current foreground app (my app will be in the background at that moment. I may use audio player or voip for this)

b) Detect when new application became foreground app

Comment: I'm not quite sure why you would want this unless you're developing a jailbreak tweak...

Comment: I upvoted the question. While I work developing AppStore apps, I still think this is a legit development question.

Comment: 2qegal: First of all, private API are perfectly legit thing for enterprise in-house or ad-hoc distribution apps. Secondly, private API work on NON jailbroken devices. So, my question has no relation to jailbreak tweaks.

Comment: Private API's work on non-jailbroken devices but Apple typically rejects apps that utilize private API's. You're right about the enterprise in-house/ad-hoc distribution part though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like this question has this answer for mine question.
[how to determine which apps are background and which app is foreground on iOS by application id](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8252396/how-to-determine-which-apps-are-background-and-which-app-is-foreground-on-ios-by)

It boils down to SBFrontmostApplicationDisplayIdentifier private API