# checks current running processes,iphone

Tags: iphone, ipad, jailbreak

Can we find out the list of process which are currently running on in iOS programmatically?

[image]

Somewhat similar to shown here

http://www.techet.net/sysstat/
shown at process tab

Suggestions are always welcome.
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [this other answer I literally just posted](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11574932/119114).

Take a look at the modified Darwin C-code I posted:

[darwin.c](http://pastebin.com/EDWtGrhc)

[darwin.h](http://pastebin.com/kiNEU669)

If you look in there, inside `OS_get_table()`, you'll find a bunch of commented out `printf` statements.  If you uncomment and change those, storing the data in some kind of usable data structure, you can collect all this type of information.

**Note** don't just uncomment all the `printf` statements and expect that code to work, though.  iOS has limits on the rate at which apps can write to std out, so you'll get throttled if you have tons of `printf`s in a short period of time.