# iOS Processes Info (pid, uid, cpu, mem, ...)

Tags: objective-c, ios, jailbreak

I'm writing app like System Activity in Mac. I used modified darwin.h and darwin.c from [this topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11573822/get-the-bundle-id-of-app-from-pid-in-ios).
But it seems that it shows correct info only for certain fields (and some time ago it showed all correct info but only for current process - this app), for everything else it shows correct only pid, process name, group/owner. Everything else like cpu/mem/disk usage is nulled. I think it may be something with sandbox or security. Tried to move application to /Applications and setting root/wheel 755 but it's not work, still zeroed values.

Here's my output : [click](http://pastebin.com/7YLx5DdJ)

Code changed in darwin.c : [click](http://pastebin.com/0QEucecj), written after a lot of commented printf lines

Also there is a free apps approved in AppStore like SystemInfo (com.lymbilesoft.systeminfoliteforiphone) that shows detailed info about disk and processes, so how do it work? Tried nm-ing it's binary but did not find something useful.
Can someone please help me with it?

Comment: Can you share your code in your output?

Comment: It was long time ago since I worked on it, this is what I've [found in backups](http://pastebin.com/8R5r1rZB). It should give correct results if you run this as root.

Comment: did you manage to get the cpu usage? Please reply if you managed to fix your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if this is the **only** problem, but it certainly is possible that your app needs to run as `root` for this to work correctly.

However, simply installing the app in `/Applications`, doing `chown root.wheel`, and `chmod 755` will not cause it to **run** as `root`.  It will still run as user `mobile`.

In order to get the app to **run** as `root`, [see this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8796556/119114)

I've used this technique successfully, and if you have a jailbroken phone, you can navigate to `/Applications/Cydia.app` and see that this *launch script* is how Cydia does this, too.

Comment: Thanks for hint, but still not working - zeroed values. Anyway there's should be a way to do it like in that App Store approved app.

Answer (score 0):

I use `ps aux` from the Terminal/Command Line. That gives me all the stuff I need, regarding your concerns.