# close all apps directly from Springboard without opening the switcher panel?

Tags: ios, objective-c, jailbreak, tweak

**Jailbroken iPhone iOS 7**: Is it possible to close all apps in the background directly from Springboard without opening the background switcher panel?

I'm trying to do that in this way:

```
SBAppSliderController* switcherController = MSHookIvar<SBAppSliderController*>(self, "_switcherController");

[_switcherController _quitAppAtIndex:0];
```

and then I make a `for` cycle in this way

```
- (void)_quitAppAtIndex:(unsigned int)arg1 {
   if (arg1 == 0) {
      for (NSString *appID in [self applicationList]) {
        if (![appID isEqualToString:@"com.apple.springboard"])
            [self _quitAppAtIndex:[[self applicationList] indexOfObject:appID]];
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: This is most definitely possible. In fact, I wouldn't be surprised if it's been asked and answered already. What is not working in your code?

Comment: The system crashed with a reboot

Comment: You should be able to at least isolate the line causing the problem. Did you try any other answers here, like this one? http://stackoverflow.com/q/15008258/381233

Comment: Why is there an argument for `_quitAppAtIndex:`?  If you want to get good, quick answers to your coding problems, post code that's well-formatted, clean, and clear, demonstrating *only* the problem you're asking about.  Make it easy for us to help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no `%orig` in your `_quitAppAtIndex`:, so it won't kill any app and may cause a respring (not reboot).

For my advice (not tested):

```
SBAppSliderController* switcherController = MSHookIvar<SBAppSliderController*>(self, "_switcherController");

for (int i = [switcherController applicationList].count; i > 0; i--)
    [switcherController _quitAppAtIndex:i];
```

Hope this can help, and this is what I actually did in Slide2Kill 7.