# Close another iOS app through a button

Tags: ios

I made an app. Now I want to close an other app (not mine) - does anybody here know how that is going to work?

I don't want to publish the App in the App Store - so it is only for private purposes but I dont want to jailbreak my iPhone.

Comment: Only if your app is called iOS :D

Comment: Unless your app is a jailbreak tweak, you can't.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For security reason an app cannot control another one.

You **cannot** do it.

Comment: Yes, I know but I don't want to publish the App in the App Store

Comment: He means you _can't_. The sandbox _prevents_ it. There is no other way around it without being jailbroken.

Answer (score 0):

It's **not** possible - your app is contained within its own sandbox separate from other apps on the device.

For more information, you can read [Secutiy Overview: Code Security](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Security/Conceptual/Security_Overview/SecuritySvcs/SecuritySvcs.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40002650-SW5)  in the iOS Developer Library.

Comment: Yes I know but I want to use the app only for me and dont publish it in the App Store

Comment: Unless you're jailbroken (which you haven't specified in your question), there is no way to do this from a standard application - even if it's not going to be submitted to the App Store. You can accomplish this if your device is jailbroken and your application (i.e., a jailbreak tweak) runs as root using [methods described here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15777292/269970).