# How to find which app is running on foreground in iphone

Tags: ios, multithreading, multitasking

I am doing one app user install my and did go background but in my want recognize which application is on foreground. How to find this when my is in background still my app was run and which application is running currently.  Please anybody help me i am new to ios .

Thanks in advance.

Comment: i don't think you can in a nonjailbreaked device

Comment: Possible Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15032142/get-the-name-of-the-current-foreground-app

Answer (score 1):

You cannot find out what other apps are running in iOS