# detect which is the current running application in device in iOS.

Tags: ios

Is there any possible way to track which application is running in foreground in device in iOS. 
For example if I am using facebook app I need to get the name of the application from my application.

If SMS application is used I need to get the name of the application from my application.

Comment: Did you used SpringBoardServices. Have a look of it http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8252396/how-to-determine-which-apps-are-background-and-which-app-is-foreground-on-ios-by

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible. All you can do is get a list of currently running tasks using a systcl call.