# How to check which app is in foreground mode from running apps list?

Tags: ios8, iphone-privateapi, ios-frameworks, ios8.2

I am using iOS 8. I am performing experiments and not submitted in appstore. I want to know which app is in foreground mode in device.I am using [applist](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8252396/how-to-determine-which-apps-are-background-and-which-app-is-foreground-on-ios-by) but I did not get solution.

Please help me if any solution is there or not. Please explain me what is the reason.

Comment: Pls, give me solution for this question.