# Can I access information about other iOS apps beyond the scope of my app's sandbox?

Tags: ios, sandbox

Is it possible to create an app that knows if other apps are running?  For instance could an app be made that tracks data like this: You currently have 3 apps running. You spent the most amount of time this week on the Facebook app: 20 hrs.

Is this possible, or is it impossible to get this data from other iOS apps?

Comment: I think you can use an App Extension, so this extension would be in te NC and checking all the user activity, I dont see another solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not possible to create an application that tracks the status of other application using public APIs provided by Apple.

It may be possible using private APIs, but your app will be rejected upon submission to the app store.  Take a look at this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8252396/how-to-determine-which-apps-are-background-and-which-app-is-foreground-on-ios-by).

Answer (score 0):

There is no way of doing that on the device but you could try using a VPN connection similar to what [Onavo](http://www.onavo.com/apps/iphone_extend_help) does and inspect the traffic on the server side.