# Is it possible to prevent other apps from running?

Tags: ios, iphone

New to IOS programming and was wondering if it is possible to develop an app which will stop other applications from running

for example : When my app is activated user will not be able to run twitter and facebook until my app is deactivated ?

Thanks

Comment: Not possible on iOS. Apps run in sandbox mode and they don't have access to other apps.

Comment: surely NO, if iOS device is not jailbroken

Comment: Yes sure... download my Social Network App that disables Facebook on your phone... that sounds like a reasonable thing to allow...?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No you can't have access to interact with the other apps because of sandbox environment.

> App Sandboxing
>
> A sandbox is a set of fine-grained controls that limit the app's access to files, preferences, network resources, hardware, and so on. As part of the sandboxing process, the system installs each app in its own sandbox directory, which acts as the home for the app and its data.

https://developer.apple.com/app-sandboxing/

https://stackoverflow.com/a/35709745/8023444

Comment: Thanks @Nikhles Bagdiya