# Get priority and uptime from pid? ( iOS )

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, process

This is for an app intended for the app store.

Using the code [from here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4312613/can-we-retrieve-the-applications-currently-running-in-iphone-and-ipad), I can get a list of running processes and their pids. However, I've found several apps in the appstore ([like this one](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/battery-memory-system-status/id497937231?mt=8) that have also retrieved each process's **priority** and **start time.**

(Note: I don't care whether it's uptime, for how long the process has been active, or the wall clock date/time the process started).

Is there any documented way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

Here is the code to get all the process related info you want such as Name, Priority,StartDate, ParentID,Status. [Here](https://github.com/Shmoopi/iOS-System-Services) is the link to get full resource with demo.

```
// List of process information including PID's, Names, PPID's, and Status'
+ (NSMutableArray *)processesInformation {
    // Get the list of processes and all information about them
    @try {
        // Make a new integer array holding all the kernel processes
        int mib[4] = {CTL_KERN, KERN_PROC, KERN_PROC_ALL, 0};

        // Make a new size of 4
        size_t miblen = 4;

        size_t size = 0;
        int st = sysctl(mib, miblen, NULL, &size, NULL, 0);

        // Set up the processes and new process struct
        struct kinfo_proc *process = NULL;
        struct kinfo_proc *newprocess = NULL;

        // do, while loop rnning through all the processes
        do {
            size += size / 10;
            newprocess = realloc(process, size);

            if (!newprocess) {
                if (process) free(process);
                // Error
                return nil;
            }

            process = newprocess;
            st = sysctl(mib, miblen, process, &size, NULL, 0);

        } while (st == -1 && errno == ENOMEM);

        if (st == 0) {
            if (size % sizeof(struct kinfo_proc) == 0) {
                int nprocess = size / sizeof(struct kinfo_proc);

                if (nprocess) {
                    NSMutableArray *array = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

                    for (int i = nprocess - 1; i >= 0; i--) {

                        NSString *processID = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%d", process[i].kp_proc.p_pid];
                        NSString *processName = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%s", process[i].kp_proc.p_comm];
                        NSString *processPriority = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%d", process[i].kp_proc.p_priority];
                        NSDate   *processStartDate = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSince1970:process[i].kp_proc.p_un.__p_starttime.tv_sec];
                        NSString       *processParentID = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%d", [self parentPIDForProcess:(int)process[i].kp_proc.p_pid]];
                        NSString       *processStatus = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%d", (int)process[i].kp_proc.p_stat];
                        NSString       *processFlags = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%d", (int)process[i].kp_proc.p_flag];

                        // Check to make sure all values are valid (if not, make them)
                        if (processID == nil || processID.length <= 0) {
                            // Invalid value
                            processID = @"Unkown";
                        }
                        if (processName == nil || processName.length <= 0) {
                            // Invalid value
                            processName = @"Unkown";
                        }
                        if (processPriority == nil || processPriority.length <= 0) {
                            // Invalid value
                            processPriority = @"Unkown";
                        }
                        if (processStartDate == nil) {
                            // Invalid value
                            processStartDate = [NSDate date];
                        }
                        if (processParentID == nil || processParentID.length <= 0) {
                            // Invalid value
                            processParentID = @"Unkown";
                        }
                        if (processStatus == nil || processStatus.length <= 0) {
                            // Invalid value
                            processStatus = @"Unkown";
                        }
                        if (processFlags == nil || processFlags.length <= 0) {
                            // Invalid value
                            processFlags = @"Unkown";
                        }

                        // Create an array of the objects
                        NSArray *ItemArray = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:processID, processName, processPriority, processStartDate, processParentID, processStatus, processFlags, nil];

                        // Create an array of keys
                        NSArray *KeyArray = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"PID", @"Name", @"Priority", @"StartDate", @"ParentID", @"Status", @"Flags", nil];

                        // Create the dictionary
                        NSDictionary *dict = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithObjects:ItemArray forKeys:KeyArray];

                        // Add the objects to the array
                        [array addObject:dict];
                    }

                    // Make sure the array is usable
                    if (array.count <= 0) {
                        // Error, nothing in array
                        return nil;
                    }

                    // Free the process
                    free(process);

                    // Successful
                    return array;
                }
            }
        }

        // Something failed
        return nil;
    }
    @catch (NSException * ex) {
        // Error
        return nil;
    }
}

// Parent ID for a certain PID
+ (int)parentPIDForProcess:(int)pid {
    // Get the parent ID for a certain process
    @try {
        // Set up the variables
        struct kinfo_proc info;
        size_t length = sizeof(struct kinfo_proc);
        int mib[4] = { CTL_KERN, KERN_PROC, KERN_PROC_PID, pid };

        if (sysctl(mib, 4, &info, &length, NULL, 0) < 0)
            // Unknown value
            return -1;

        if (length == 0)
            // Unknown value
            return -1;

        // Make an int for the PPID
        int PPID = info.kp_eproc.e_ppid;

        // Check to make sure it's valid
        if (PPID <= 0) {
            // No PPID found
            return -1;
        }

        // Successful
        return PPID;
    }
    @catch (NSException *exception) {
        // Error
        return -1;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thx for answer. Do you know how to get info from processFlags? I mean what have got number means.