# How can i get background running applications detail in my Application for iOS?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode

I want to develop one application which should be  monitoring how much application is running on how much time on my I-Phone Device(including internet browsers).

Please share your idea regarding this post.

little similar like this:
https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/system-manager/id455736462?mt=8

thanks

Answer (score 7):

You really can't since Apple has placed very restrictive guidelines on Apps for iOS.
Although with some low level call you might get some running process information.

Because of the sandbox environment you might not be abele to much more information then that.

Also app's in background are suspended if they have no background running flaggs (voip, audio, location or accessory). Also if the system gets low on memory app that are suspended get killed and there memory freed up.

---

What you can do:

- Try the [List of All Processes](http://developer.apple.com/legacy/mac/library/#qa/qa2001/qa1123.html) OS X code which
- [Can we retrieve the applications currently running in iPhone and iPad](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4312613/can-we-retrieve-the-applications-currently-running-in-iphone-and-ipad)

But keep in mind the restiction placed on you app by Apple: [The iOS Environment](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/TheiOSEnvironment/TheiOSEnvironment.html), thus that there are app availble in the appstore that do what you want does not mean that you app will be allowed.

Comment: @SaurabhJain I have no idea, also you should ask this as a question not a comment. And if you are going to ask it don't ask it on StackOverflow since it is not related to programming.