# How to know some particular app (FB , Instagram) is opened in IOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c, multithreading

I want to know some app (FB , Instagram) is opened or not. Clearly to say, i want to look at user interaction after user put my app in background and open some apps ( Like FB , Instagram ). Is it possible in IOS?

Comment: not possible with any public API.

Comment: And with any private API? IOS doest allow us to look at user interactions with other apps ? Is there any doc in which it is written ?

Comment: Check here : [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13491839/how-can-i-get-background-running-applications-detail-in-my-application-for-ios](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13491839/how-can-i-get-background-running-applications-detail-in-my-application-for-ios)