# iOS: How to differentiate an actual App from the list of running processes obtainged from kinfo_proc?

Tags: iphone, ios

I'm referring to this link:
[Can we retrieve the applications currently running in iPhone and iPad](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4312613/can-we-retrieve-the-applications-currently-running-in-iphone-and-ipad)

The result retuns a list of running processes. However, I need only the actual Apps on the iPhone or iPad (those Apps which the user can launch and control). How is this possible?

Comment: Do you mean a list of all installed Apps, or a filtered list of running processes that don't include system services and such?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**You cannot get a list of other apps the user has installed.** Determining process information is a totally different beast from determining apps "which the user can launch and control".

If you need to launch a specific app, you can see if it supports a custom url protocol but you're out of luck for querying apps for the whole device.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, you can get a list of installed apps, and event notifications of install/uninstall, but using private APIs.

Take a look at Preferences app to find out how. I can't tell you at the moment the method to get them, but I got it from that place some months ago.