# Is it programatically possible to stop particular iOS apps from running on a unjailbroken ipad / iphone?

Tags: ios

Would it be possible to write an iOS app that could prevent other apps from running on an unjailbroken iphone / ipad?

This would be for legitimate purposes, e.g. I turn the app on, hand my iPad to my child and I don't have to worry that they'll delete my photos or browse the web.

Comment: Can you please confirm whether this is for a jailbroken device or for normal iPhone. Please add the tag `jailbreak` if it is specific to that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, Not programmatically. You cannot control another app from your app unless the iPhone is jail broken. However you can get a list of processes in iOS as mentioned in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4312705/1730272). You can try to send SIGKILL to terminate them if you are not planning to release this app to appstore(**Not recommended**).

> e.g. I turn the app on, hand my iPad to my child and I don't have to
>   worry that they'll delete my photos or browse the web.

Regarding the above point, probably the easiest solution is to check [Guided Access](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT5509) for this purpose.

Use Guided Access to:

- Temporarily restrict your iOS device to a particular app
- Disable areas of the screen that aren’t relevant to a task, or areas
  where an accidental gesture might cause a distraction
- Disable the hardware buttons

You can tap Settings > General > Accessibility > Guided Access to set up Guided Access. From there you can:

- Turn Guided Access on or off
- Set a passcode that controls the use of Guided Access and prevents someone from leaving an active session
- Set whether the device can go to sleep during a session

**Start a Guided Access session**

- Open the app you want to run.
- Triple-click the Home button.
- Adjust settings for the session, then click Start.

**Disable app controls and areas of the app screen**

- Circle any part of the screen you want to disable.
- Use the handles to adjust the area.

**Ignore all screen touches**

- Turn off Touch.

**Keep iPhone, iPad, or iPod touch from switching from portrait to landscape or from responding to any other motions**

- Turn off Motion.

**End a Guided Access session**

- Triple-click the Home button.
- Enter the Guided Access passcode.

All these details are taken from the above link.

Answer (score 3):

It's a setting in the iOS called restrictions (`Settings` -> `General` -> `Restrictions`) and **cannot** be done programmatically.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to answer. I was unaware of the restrictions options.

Comment: Hello @graver , I show one application in app store can set restrictions on off the other device using some provisional profile . how is it possible ? have you any idea? Thanks for rpl