# Get all running apps PIDs

Tags: ios, pid

I'm running on a jailbroken iPhone and creating a tweak. I need a way to get all currently running apps PID's.

Is this possible? What would be the best way to do it?

Thanks! Any help is appreciated

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can we retrieve the applications currently running in iPhone and iPad](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4312613/can-we-retrieve-the-applications-currently-running-in-iphone-and-ipad)

Answer (score 0):

You could always slice up the output of 'ps'. This might give you some help:
http://techtips.salon.com/iphone-ps-command-options-300.html

I assume, since you can run it in a terminal emulator you may be able to exec it in your app and read the output.