# Read badge value of other application on iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c

Is it possible to get the badge value of another iOS application?

For example, if I want my app to know how much unread messages the user has, can I simply look at the badge of the message application and read the integer value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No this is not possible, your app is sandboxed and can not acces other apps.

Comment: Ok thank you; but is there any possibility to just get the number of the unread messages, independently from the applications badge?

Comment: No, there is no API that allows this

Comment: Whilst you are correct that my app cannot access the badge number of other apps, indeed it is possible to get the currently running apps: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4312613/can-we-retrieve-the-applications-currently-running-in-iphone-and-ipad

Comment: @returntrue that code is not really App Store save.

Comment: @rckoenes that code is perfectly App Store safe. It only makes use of sys/sysctl.h which is a public C API.

Comment: @davidf2281yes you might be right about that, looks like it might actually work. Not sure if the review board will allow it, since they are a bit picky about it.